# Android Cover Flow gallery and remove space between

Tags: android, image-gallery, coverflow

I want to implement cover flow view as shown below image.
I also tried with cover flow but cant achieved perfect view as show in image. Reduce the space between the items.
[image]

```
 this.fancyCoverFlow.setSpacing(-90);
```

I tried with this line and its working but other problem occur as shown below image not getting same spec to left and right .
And scroll from left to right working fine but scroll from right to left not in correct way.

[image]

**Updated**:
[Try with this code](https://github.com/dolphinwang/ImageCoverFlow)

Comment: Can please paste your code how you are creating this type of Gallery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i want the same view how did you do that Please help me to do the same thing. thanks for your help

Comment: This is only for cover flow or creating the full view??

Comment: @kyogs Your update answer is not working? i can't understand that library project also..

Comment: @kyogs Don't put the code like this to misguide the person If you have right implementation then post it don't waste the time of others..

Comment: i stuck in same can any one help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911244/fancycoverflow-layout-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 3):

Hey you can try: [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow)
and [android-coverflow-widget](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)

Comment: @rokonid i seen this fancycover flow demo but i cant remove space between two image. i want view as shown in image.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow

This should be of help for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i seen this fancycover flow demo but i cant remove space between two image. i want view as shown in image.

Answer (score 1):

if you implement gallery  as use FancyCoverFlow, you can use `this.fancyCoverFlow.setSpacing(-90);` -90 may be modify

Comment: i also tried with this and its remove spec but other problem occur.Spec is not same to left and right.

Comment: this should be accepted answer..i vote up..really saved my time

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
this.fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedAlpha(1.0f);
this.fancyCoverFlow.setActionDistance(FancyCoverFlow.ACTION_DISTANCE_AUTO);
this.fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedScale(0.75f);
```

in your code, i hope this will help you.

Comment: Providing some details about how this solves the problem would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced same problem, use following code in your code (FancyCoverFlow.java) file.

```
private void initialize()  {
this.transformationCamera = new Camera();
this.setSpacing(-200); // specifies space between images. }
```

In my case I am using FancyCoverFlow which extends Gallery.