# Android Horizontal Scroll VIew like gallery

Tags: android, android-animation, android-scrollview, android-gallery, android-scroll

I want to make horizontal scroll view in android like gallery view, in which centered image zooms in while scroll. Often seen in web but I haven't found one in andriod. Here is an example from one iOS app.

[image]

I have tried with HorizontalScrollView, ListView, ViewPager but not able to reproduce zoomed Effect in center while scroll, and next images comes from behind.

Comment: What was wrong with HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce zoomed Effect in center while scroll, and next images comes from behind

Comment: well... maybe you didn't search good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583033/android-cover-flow-gallery-and-remove-space-between "Cover Flow" style is what you need (but remove the angle). In the question and answers you have a few libraries.

Comment: here you have more: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/154

Comment: Try using Coverflow third party....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **CoverFlow** .Its a view for Android with several fancy effects.

1. https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow
2. https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow

Comment: I am using moondroid/CoverFlow, but just the one issue, I want to remove endless loop. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Directly Use View  Pager with DepthPage Transformation to Acheive as you like according to Android Documentation.

You can Acheive like :[Demo of ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/anim_page_transformer_depth.webm)

To achieve this kind of View
[View Pager with Transformation Speed in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use a ViewPager inside a TabHost to get something close to what you are looking for.

```
<TabHost
        android:id="@+id/calendar_add_edit_th"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tabs_com"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="37dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_tabs_com"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_tabs_com">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#fff" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
```