# Cannot overlap images using CoverFlow in Android

Tags: java, android, adapter, coverflow

I'm using [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) to show a CoverView in my Android App.

All works fine but the only think I can't do is overlap the items.

This is what I'm trying to do: [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JikrB.jpg)

I tried using

```
coverFlow.setSpacing(-90);
```

or other configuration (such as -200 or -50), but setSpacing doesn't change anything in my final result.

This is the Adapter:

```
coverFlowAdapter = new FancyCoverFlowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getCoverFlowItem(int position, View reuseableView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            v = reuseableView;
            if (v == null) {
                v = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.coverflo_item, viewGroup, false);
            }
            //do my stuff...
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            //do my stuff...
        }

        @Override
        public Home getItem(int position) {
            //do my stuff...
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

These are coverFlow setting:

```
coverFlow.setAdapter(coverFlowAdapter);
coverFlow.setUnselectedSaturation(0.0f);
coverFlow.setSpacing(0);
coverFlow.setMaxRotation(0);
coverFlow.setScaleDownGravity(0.2f);
coverFlow.setReflectionEnabled(false);
coverFlow.setUnselectedAlpha(1.0f);
coverFlow.setActionDistance(FancyCoverFlow.ACTION_DISTANCE_AUTO);
coverFlow.setUnselectedScale(0.75f);
```

There is another StackOverflow question about this issue, but is not useful:

[Android Cover Flow gallery and remove space between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583033/android-cover-flow-gallery-and-remove-space-between)

I tried also other sources, but I found only coverFlow libraries that use image as item, while I need to use my custom layout.

Thanks.

Comment: With "overlap" I mean remove space between items